# Regex Split by spaces but ignoring spaces between words

Tags: java, regex

How can I do regex Split on a string on whitespace but ignoring the whitespace between words?

The string looks like:

```
1 IT1103 Kabellose Maus Freemove 5 23.07.2018 30 150,00
```

I want to split the string like and save it into DataTable

```
1
IT1103
Kabellose Maus Freemove
5 
23.07.2018
30 
150,00
```

Could anyone help please?

Thanks
Bonnie

Comment: What do you consider a word?

Comment: [You may use this regex `(?i)(?:(?<![a-z])\s+|\s+(?![a-z]))`](https://regex101.com/r/6pevYk/1)

Comment: You really should have field separators in your data.  A regex will not be smart enough in all cases to get it right.

Comment: What did you try? [mcve] please.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
String input ="1 IT1103 Kabellose Maus Freemove 5 23.07.2018 30 150,00";
final String PATTERN = "(?<=\\d)\\s|\\s(?=\\d)";
String[] array = input.split(PATTERN);
for(String str : array)
{
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

**output:**

```
1
IT1103
Kabellose Maus Freemove
5
23.07.2018
30
150,00
```

**regex:** https://regex101.com/r/MN6juN/2

**explanations:**

`(?<=\\d)\\s|\\s(?=\\d)` is a regex that will take into account only spaces that are followed/preceded by a digit, therefore `Kabellose Maus Freemove` will be treated as a whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than Allans solution, but more verbose:

```
String tmp = input.replaceAll ("([0-9]) ([0-9a-zA-Z])", "\1\n\2")
String out = tmp.replaceAll ("([a-zA-Z]) ([0-9])", "\1\n\2")
```

- first break, when blank between two digits or digit and String
- then break that, when a blank between char and digit